# Issue with define_method in Ruby 3.0

Tags: ruby, ruby-3

I'm working on an upgrade from Ruby 2.7 to 3.0 and faced an issue with the keyword arguments change.

Previously we used define_method in our code for some purposes. However, with the keyword arguments change, it can no longer handle an array of arguments properly anymore.

```
class Foo
  def test(a: 1, b: 2)
    puts a
    puts b
  end

  old_method = instance_method(:test)

  define_method(:test) do |*args, &block|
    old_method.bind(self).call(*args, &block)
  end
end

Foo.new.test(a: 1)
```

This will raise  `wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0) (ArgumentError)`. And it previously worked in Ruby 2.7. Is there anything we can do to get the *args to work again?

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
  define_method(:test) do |*args, **kwords, &block|
    old_method.bind(self).call(*args, **kwords, &block)
  end
```

Ruby `3.0` is changing the handling of method arguments which give a deprecation warning in `2.7`.  There is some unexpected behavior including a keywords in a `*args` array.  This had to be done using a hash and there needs to be more of a distinction between a hash argument and keywords.  So in ruby `3.x` you need to capture an arbitrary collection of keywords in a double splat because they cannot be included in the splat argument.

Mostly my understanding is shaky but I read this as an explicit example in the explanation of the changed to the arguments in the release notes for ruby `3.0`.

Comment: [Official Explanation](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2019/12/12/separation-of-positional-and-keyword-arguments-in-ruby-3-0/) Scroll down to "Handling argument delegation"

Comment: @MarlinPierce: I see why your solution is correct. The OP claims that his buggy solution had worked before Ruby 2.7. Do you have an explanation for this?

Comment: @user1934428 Good point.  I'm glad I waited to see if it worked first though.  My understanding is a little shaky but I think I recall this as an explicit example in the documentation for the change.